# The XNA redistributable isn't in the prerequisites list; how do I include it when publishing?

Tags: xna-4.0, publishing

So I created a small project in XNA 4.0, and wanted to try and publish it, and so I did.
Yet when attempting to install it on a different computer it didn't seem to work.

I've read and studied about how the process of publishing works, and I saw someone in a different thread asking the same question as me, then I realized that
inside the prerequisites list which is in `PROJECT -> PROPERTIES -> Publish`,
the XNA redistributable wasn't there therefore it wasn't checked, and when attempting to install it on a different computer they needed to install redistributable on their own
to make it work.

Any idea why isn't the redistributable in the list? Maybe this isn't even
the problem and if that's case any ideas of what IS the problem? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 4):

XNA things aren't in the prerequisites list for me either. Instead of that, go to the same location and click "Application Files", then make sure the Publish Status of the XNA libraries are set to "Prerequisite". To demonstrate, here's a screenshot of my settings for a new XNA project.

[image: Default XNA Settings]
(Click image for full size.)

Comment: First of, thank you for asnwering and sorry for being late for replying since internet was off for couple of days. My Application files are exactly same the as yours. Yet when entering with another computer it doesn't install the XNA redistributable. (they were that way before, I didn't have to change anything). Perhaps I did something wrong?

Comment: @ShaiRoemi Are you sure you're using ClickOnce deployment? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb464156(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx#click_once

Answer (score 0):

According to the EULA you can't simply include the XNA DLLs with your game - you need to add a link to the installer for the redist.

Here's the XNA FAQ on installers/prerequisites etc http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/1989.aspx